# (Flask, d3) Uncaught ReferenceError: d3 is not defined

Tags: javascript, python, d3.js

I am new to d3.js. I am trying to deploy [this example](https://gist.github.com/mmparker/3670696) on my Flask application. However, it constantly gives me an error- "Uncaught ReferenceError: d3 is not defined". I even downloaded the d3.v2.min.js file on the server, but it doesn't work. 
Here is my html code:

```
<html>
<head>

    <title>Quarterly Report to the City and County of Denver</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" src=""{{ url_for('static', filename='js/d3.v2.min.js') }}" charset="utf-8"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ url_for('static', filename='js/makeMultiTable.js') }}"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ url_for('static', filename='js/setupPlot.js') }}"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ url_for('static', filename='js/drawLinePlot.js') }}"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ url_for('static', filename='js/toggleStat.js') }}"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ url_for('static', filename='js/load_qtrly_stats.js') }}"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/line_plot.css') }}" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/table.css') }}" />

</head>

<body>

    <div id="table"></div>

    <div id="plot"></div>

</body>
```

Comment: Looks like you got syntax error: ` <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ url_for('static', filename='js/d3.v2.min.js') }}" charset="utf-8"></script>`, you got 2 double quotes after src

Answer (score 2):

```
<title>Quarterly Report to the City and County of Denver</title>
<!--- Fixed syntax error in the below line --->
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ url_for('static', filename='js/d3.v2.min.js') }}" charset="utf-8"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ url_for('static', filename='js/makeMultiTable.js') }}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ url_for('static', filename='js/setupPlot.js') }}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ url_for('static', filename='js/drawLinePlot.js') }}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ url_for('static', filename='js/toggleStat.js') }}"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ url_for('static', filename='js/load_qtrly_stats.js') }}"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/line_plot.css') }}" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/table.css') }}" />
</head>
<body>
<div id="table"></div>
<div id="plot"></div>
</body>
```